# Update graph on MainWindow with pushButton using PyQt4

Tags: matplotlib, widget, pyqt4, embed

I am mimicking [this simple graph embedding example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html). I successfully embed a graph in my GUI and it works perfectly when I press the pushbutton. But the problem is it does not update when I click the pushbutton second time or more. It throws the following error

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "centralwidget", which already has a layout
```

Here is my code so far:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100, stores = [], prices = []):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.prices = prices
        self.stores = stores
        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.setMaximumSize(800, 300)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.clear() # To clear the axis every time and make new plot 
        y_pos = np.arange(4)
        self.axes.bar(y_pos, self.prices)
        self.axes.set_xticks(y_pos, minor=False)
        self.axes.set_xticklabels(self.stores, fontdict=None, minor=False)
```

For the pushbutton I have the following method

```
def button_click(self):
.......
     # Here is some logic that return prices and stores list which is used in self.sc
     self.l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
     self.sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.centralwidget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100, stores=stores, prices= prices)
     self.l.addWidget(self.sc)
if (self.l.count() > 0): self.sc.deleteLater() # Added in new Edit but it also does not work
```

I have tried many options:

```
1. self.sc.deleteLater() # It just removes the graph from GUI
2. self.sc.axes.clear() and self.sc.axes.cla() # Does nothing but returns above mentioned error
3. I deleted the layout from central widget and set it again but still nothing happened.
4. I tried this too --> `if (self.l.count() > 0): self.sc.deleteLater()` but it just delete the whole graph
```

Where am I doing it wrong ? Please guide. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear why you want to add the FigureCanvas a second time to the GUI. But as we don't have a [mcve] of the issue, it's impossible to help.

Comment: It is possible that I may be doing it in a naive or wrong way. But the objective is to update the graph with the new data which I'll get as a list of `stores` and `prices` whenever I click the pushbutton. Is there a better way for this ?

Comment: I just figured out that you were right. I put the FigureCanvas back into the __init__() and it works like I wanted. Thanks for pointing it out